# Check the equality of eyes, nose and chin - realizable?

Tags: android, opencv

I want to program an Android application, in which you have two pictures with a face in each picture. For these pictures, I want to check the equality of eyes, nose and chin.

The output of this check should be something like percentage results (for example: eyes match: 30% etc.).

Is there a way to realize this?

Would be super glad if somebody could help me!

Btw: I read through some OpenCV Threads already but I'm not sure if it is possible, because I didn't try anything with OpenCV, yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's realizable. Difficulty depends on what do you mean by "equality of eyes, ..." - if just want to check whether eyes on 2 images looks exactly (or almost exactly) the same, than just use template matching technique. If you want to take 2 pictures of the same face, but with different position, rotation, lighting, etc and make app which will say "hey that's the same person!" well... that's realizable, but MUCH HARDER.

Comment: First Thank you for your post mate. I wanted to check two different faces . Would be cool if you could provide some code to work with. Thank you :)